# Git branching-strategy Devops CI/CD

Tags: git

I have gone through a few youtube videos and some documentation about git branching strategy but as per my my understanding below are the process we have to follow

1. Let's consider I have two bracnhes, one is a master and another one is a development branch, both branches are having same code.
2. Now based on the new requirement creating new feature from development branch.
3. checkout the feature branch and doing some changes to it and push the changes into the feature/audio remote branch.

```
git checkout -b feature/audio origin/feature/audio 
git add filename
git commit -m "audio feature"
git push
```

4. Development team raise the pull request from origin/feature/audio to development branch to merge the changes into the development branch.
5. After merging the code azure pipeline will start the build and deploy the changes into the test environment.
6. Testing team started test cases all the test cases are passed and they will share the QA sign-off message.
7. Then the DevOps team creates a release branch (release/v1.0.1) from the development branch, in case of any last minutes, fixes the dev team adds some commits inside the release/v1.0.1 branch and raises the pull request to development and master branch.

```
git checkout -b release/v1.0.1 origin/release/v1.0.1 
git add filename
git commit -m "audio feature"
git push
```

8. After merging the changes from the release to the master branch, create a tag 1.0.1 from the master.
9. Trigger the deployment using the azure pipeline to deploy the code into a production environment.

Please correct if anything i missed in above steps

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: No, i'm just asking above steps can we applied to my real-time project or I need to add some more points about git-branching-strategy

Comment: Any systematic approach can be used systematically. Does the above meet your goals? If so, it's fine. If not, it's not fine. Git doesn't offer solutions to particular problems so much as a set of tools by which you can produce your *own* solutions to your *own* problems, but first you'll need to define what your particular problems are.

Comment: For instance: what happens if something fails QA entirely?

Comment: Hi @ Torek, If any failure during the QA testing, we will keep doing changes in releasebranch (release/v1.0.1 ) and merge the changes back to development branch and again start the deployment to test environment.

Comment: When we receive the QA sign-off from QA team then we will merge the changes from release/v1.0.1 to master branch